# Xcode usability - Multiple screens

Tags: xcode, user-interface

Is there a way to split Xcode interface when using multiple monitors?
I have 2 monitors but still haven't found an easy way to use it on more than 1 monitor (Storyboard on the left, code on the right) - Like you can do when using Intellij with Android - simple drag n drop of windows

Thanks for any tip,

Answer (score 12):

Just **right click** on a file and **Open in New Window**

Answer (score 3):

Go to File > New > Window

[As detailed by Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingMultipleWorkspaces.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26730131)

Comment: Create multiple workspace windows by choosing File > New > Window. Each window can be customized independently of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out just now after using XCode for several years.
You can configure how XCode responds to navigation/linked editors etc from the navigation tab in XCode Preferences.

I set "Optional Navigation" to "Uses Destination Chooser", which apparently was the missing link for using two monitors, since you can e.g. link the editor window with a storyboard view. I also set "Double click Navigation" to "Uses separate window". With these settings, the summary at the bottom looks like this:

```
 - Click: Open in new window
 - Option-click : Displays destination chooser
 - Option-Shift-click: Opens in next editor
 - Double-click: Open in new window
```